# getting error while creating dedicated vsi from softlayer slcli

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to get the details of dedicated servers by using slcli(version 5.4.4)

and getting following error
"SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid): Invalid price 64 GB (Dedicated Host) (200375) provided on the order container. Please select a dedicated instance RAM price to order a dedicated instance."

command which I tried

> slcli order place --verify --billing hourly CLOUD_SERVER DALLAS13 \
>   RAM_64_UNIT_DEDICATED \
>   REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE \
>   1_GBPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS_DEDICATED_HOSTS \
>   BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2 \
>   1_IP_ADDRESS \
>   GUEST_DISK_100_GB_LOCAL_DEDICATED_HOST \
>   GUEST_DISK_100_GB_LOCAL_DEDICATED_DISK1 \
>   GUEST_CORE_16_DEDICATED \
>   OS_UBUNTU_16_04_LTS_XENIAL_XERUS_MINIMAL_64_BIT_FOR_VSI \
>   MONITORING_HOST_PING \
>   NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET \
>   AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION \
>   UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT \
>   NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING \
>   --extras '{"virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "test", "domain": "softlayer.com"}]}' \
>   --complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you did not select a Dedicated Host server where your virtual guest will be hosted.

You have to add the hostId in the option extras in front of the object "virtualGuests" the same as this example:

```
--extras '{"hostId": 12345, "virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "test", "domain": "softlayer.com"}]}'
```

You can use this slcli command to get the dedicated host available in your account:

```
slcli dedicatedhost list
```

Comment: Thanks Ojeda, I tried to get the dedicated host details but looks I don't have.  `slcli dedicatedhost list` is returning empty list. Is it mandatory to have dedicated instances just to get the price ?

Comment: Yes it is mandatory because the api server needs to verify if there is available space for the core, ram, disk, etc., you specified on the order. If you do not have dedicated host you have to create one.

Comment: If you do not to order a dedicated host you can try to order a private virtual guest, in this case you will don not need to specify the hostId.

Comment: I tried with softlayer portal then I am able to get the price for dedicated VSI and I don't have dedicated host, whats the difference

Comment: There are two options for a dedicated virtual server one of that is Auto Assign, it is for a virtual server private as I explained you above, this option automatically assign the virtual server to a server available in the datacenter that you selected, for this option you do not need a dedicated host.
The other option is Specify host, where you can store your virtual server on a specific Dedicated host.

Comment: For more information you can see the following documentation: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/vsi/vsi_dedicated.html#dedicated-virtual-servers