# SoftLayer API returned SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid error when update dedicated instance Computing Instances

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I had a dedicated instance Computing Instance with 2G guest_core and wanted to update as 4G. This scenario has been tested and verified on public instances. I got price id from package 46 and this error message was: `Invalid price 4 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores (Dedicated Host) (200315) provided on the order container. Please select a dedicated instance Computing Instance price to order a dedicated instance`

```
[Integration:softlayerGo] 2018/08/20 14:04:10 [DEBUG] Request URL:  POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder.json
[Integration:softlayerGo] 2018/08/20 14:04:10 [DEBUG] Parameters:  {"parameters":[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade","packageId":46,"prices":[{"id":200315},{"id":200339}],"properties":[{"name":"MAINTENANCE_WINDOW","value":"2018-08-20T06:04:10Z"},{"name":"NOTE_GENERAL","value":"Upgrade instance configuration."}],"virtualGuests":[{"id":60076795}]},false]}
[Integration:softlayerGo] 2018/08/20 14:04:12 [DEBUG] Status Code:  500
[Integration:softlayerGo] 2018/08/20 14:04:12 [DEBUG] Response:  {"error":"Invalid price 4 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores (Dedicated Host) (200315) provided on the order container. Please select a dedicated instance Computing Instance price to order a dedicated instance.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid"}
```

And this package could be used to assign guest_disk1 and could not find another valid package.

And I found some people suggested a host id when placing the order: [getting error while creating dedicated vsi from softlayer slcli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372654/getting-error-while-creating-dedicated-vsi-from-softlayer-slcli)

But my instance was auto assigned, so I could not find a host ID.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you go is because you are using ¨Dedicated Host¨ item prices, but you have to find just ¨Dedicated¨ items prices the same that the following item example:

```
¨4 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores (Dedicated)¨
```

Do not forget that the item prices have to be in the same location as your dedicated instance.

The dedicated instance created by auto assigned does not have ¨hostId¨ because it was auto assigned to a datacenter available and not to a dedicated host.

Try to upgrade your instance with the following items prices:

```
"prices":[
                  {  
                        "id" : 24886 //  "4 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores (Dedicated)"
                  },
                  {     "id" : 32597 //  "1 GB"
                  }
         ]
```

You can find the ¨ guest_disk1 ¨ in the same package, try searching e.g. by the "keyName": "GUEST_DISK_25_GB_SAN" depending on the disk size you want.

With the following rest api you can get the item prices available for your dedicated instance with their respective locations:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getUpgradeItemPrices
```

Body: Json

```
{
  "parameters": [
      false
  ]
}
```

If you want to include the the downgrade item prices you just have to change the data ¨false¨ to true in the json body.

The item prices that do not have locations are standard, it means that all location are available for that items.

Reference:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices/

Comment: Thanks. I found to use priceItem.keyName to filter public/private/dedicated_host cores.